# export Excel range to csv with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm trying to export a range of cells to a csv file:

```
#Specify Range
$range = $sh_in.Range("E7:F13,B17:C25").Text

#Export range to csv
$range | Export-Csv "delivery-note\del_note_csv_test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

If I take off the .Text from the Range I get a huge amount of information, including the content of the cells, and I've tried replacing .Text with the header of the info I want, but this just gives an error.  What can I do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` to select what you want (i.e. the Text property) from the returned $range array, then export to the CSV file:

```
$range = $sh_in.Range("E7:F13,B17:C25")
$range | select text | Export-Csv "delivery-note\del_note_csv_test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```